# PHP refer to other static variables in static variables

Tags: php

How do you refer to static variables in another static variable?

```
  class Test{
     public static $role = 3;
     public static $factory = ['role' => self::$role];
  }
  print_r(Test::$factory);
```

Link: https://ideone.com/0je4Mm

Error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$role' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /home/PpylVI/prog.php on line 4`

Comment: Should be either `self::$role` or `const role = 3`

Comment: The same way you refer to static variables in _any_ context. This looks like a trivial typo, to me, and you ought to have caught it!

Comment: Sorry, but I tried self::$role. And it just doesn't work. Edit and compile and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assing to a class property something that is evaluated at runtime, like, in this case, the value of the previous variable.

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

Taken from the manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Both these work:

```
<?php

   class Test{
    const ROLE = 3;
    public static $factory = ['role' => self::ROLE];
  }
  print_r(Test::$factory);

/*Array
(
    [role] => 3
)
*/


  class Test2{
    public static $factory = ['role' => 3];
  }
  print_r(Test2::$factory);
/*
Array
(
    [role] => 3
)
*/
```

Comment: Perfect answer. And I noticed that if I declare the same constant in subclass and they won't collide. Thanks! https://ideone.com/AsIUeO